# error while building maven application. com.trampoline

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.trampoline.buddyto</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sample-service</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>sample-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springfox-version>2.7.0</springfox-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trampoline.buddyto</groupId>
            <artifactId>tenant</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.trampoline.buddyto</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jkube</groupId>
                <artifactId>kubernetes-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>qa</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa2</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>qa2</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>qa4</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>qa4</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <spring.profiles.active>prod</spring.profiles.active>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Here's the error I am getting: https://pastebin.com/raw/Qe4mqUCV

I don't know what to do regarding this since I am not a java developer. I do know some basics though. I am tasked with building it and deploying it on Kubernetes using the maven-kubernetes-plugin and that's exactly what I did but it didn't work
Would appreciate if someone could help me regarding this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your company uses its own repository manager that serves as a cache:

```
com.trampoline.buddyto:tenant:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Jenkins will try to download this dependency from the repository, but it can't find it.
Sometimes these repositories will time limit the availability of snapshot versions in the repository (or disallow it in preprod / prod environment in case there is a different one for these environments).
And do note that snapshots don't belong in preprod / prod releases since you seem to be in charge of the deployments.

Of course "it works on my pc" applies here very much for developers, as maven will store this dependency in the local repository when it gets compiled locally. Possibly this dependency was never deployed to the repository.

Comment: okay, so I am missing a dependency which should be in `com.trampoline.buddyto` is that correct?

Comment: That's what the error seems to point to. I made a small correction. I assume you use Jenkins to build the code, probably turn it into a docker image to push it to the repo which Kubernetes will try to pull. I think the Jenkins process tries to find the dependency in the repo but cannot find it.

Comment: so, I was given the code with pom.xml and stuff in a zip file. all I did was extract it and I added the kubernetes plugin to it and tried running it using `mvn clean install` which resulted in the above error. I am not using jenkins.

Comment: If it is local, then you need to pull that dependency from a git repo and compile it locally. This way it will be stored in you .m2 folder and your code will compile.

Comment: hmm okay, I see. I don't even know what dependency I supposed to look at exactly since it has only mentioned the path

Comment: This is something you have to ask your colleagues. It is version `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`, which strongly points to some custom artifact somebody in your company has built.

Comment: yeah! I will do just that. Thank you! really appreciate your help.